# FAX watermark/background?

Tags: c#, fax

using the windows 7 fax service, or any other faxing library in c#,

is it possible to set a watermark or a background picture to the fax document Im generating ?

I have some tab delimited text files (multi-pages reports) i need to fax them with a giving background template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used FAX COM API, however, in any .NET application every control has a [OnPrint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onprint.aspx) event which you could override and apply watermarks etc.

Comment: The OnPaint method has PaintEventArgs which will give you access to the Graphics class. Use that to edit the print document it has methods like DrawImage/DrawString.